# Way to format gt table across a single row?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, gt

I'm trying to format my gt table with conditions and am at a bit of a standstill. Most of the examples I'm finding are formatting based off of column headers.

Here's the code for an example table with the first column named "row" w/ values 1-6. How would i get the gt table to add a color ONLY to values > 3.0 across row 1? This is my first question, apologies if I messed something up!

[image: Here's how I'd like the table to look like.]

```
library(tidyverse)  
library(gt) 

iris %>%   
  group_by(Species) %>%   
  slice_max(Sepal.Length, n=5) %>%   
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(row=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Species, row)) %>%
  mutate(Species = str_to_title(Species),
         name = gsub("\\.", " ", name)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(Species, name), values_from=value)%>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_spanner_delim(
    delim="_"
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could add `tab_style` with `cell_fill` and specify the `locations` with `columns` and `rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(gt) 
library(stringr)

iris %>%   
  group_by(Species) %>%   
  slice_max(Sepal.Length, n=5) %>%   
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(row=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Species, row)) %>%
  mutate(Species = str_to_title(Species),
         name = gsub("\\.", " ", name)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(Species, name), values_from=value)%>% 
  gt() %>%
  tab_spanner_delim(
    delim="_"
  ) %>%
  
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "lightgreen")
      
    ),
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = c(`Setosa_Sepal Length`, `Setosa_Sepal Width`,
  `Versicolor_Sepal Length`, `Versicolor_Sepal Width`, `Versicolor_Petal Length`,
    `Virginica_Sepal Length`,`Virginica_Sepal Width`, `Virginica_Petal Length`),
                
      rows = 1
    )
  )
```

-ouptut

[image]

---

#### Update

Based on the comments, if we need to make use of a condition for each column, then we could use a `for` loop to loop over the column names and add the condition layer and update the original `gt` object ('tbl1')

```
tbl1 <- iris %>%   
  group_by(Species) %>%   
  slice_max(Sepal.Length, n=5) %>%   
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(row=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Species, row)) %>%
  mutate(Species = str_to_title(Species),
         name = gsub("\\.", " ", name)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(Species, name), values_from=value)%>% 
  gt() %>%
  tab_spanner_delim(
    delim="_"
  ) 

nm1 <- names(tbl1$`_data`)[-1]

for(i in seq_along(nm1)) {
  
   tbl1 <- tbl1 %>%
     tab_style(
       style = list(
         cell_fill(color = "lightgreen")
         
       ),
       locations = cells_body(
         columns = nm1[i],
         
        rows = seq_along(tbl1$`_data`[[nm1[i]]]) == 1 &  
              tbl1$`_data`[[nm1[i]]] > 3 
       )
     )  
}
```

-output

[image]

Comment: from what I understood OP wants to highlight only those cells in row number one which have a value greater then 3 and not inform them specifically - I might be wrong though

Comment: @DPH sorry, didn't read that part earlier. updatd the post

Comment: thanks so much for both answers!! it was helpful for me to try out both ways.

Comment: super helpful, any idea how this could be applied to image urls?

Comment: @Ben Please consider to provide a reproducible example. thanks

Comment: @akrun I will add as a post now, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

if you are looking to hightlight only those cells with a value greater than 3 - meaning you want not to inform them by name like akrun did - I am afraid you have to go brute force (condition for each column). I worked for the first 5 columns as it is just repetition:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt) 

df <- iris %>%   
  group_by(Species) %>%   
  slice_max(Sepal.Length, n=5) %>%   
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(row=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Species, row)) %>%
  mutate(Species = str_to_title(Species),
         name = gsub("\\.", " ", name)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(Species, name), values_from=value) 

df%>% 
  gt() %>% 
 tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "lightgreen")
      ),
    locations = cells_body(
                 columns =  vars(`Setosa_Sepal Length`),
                 rows = row == 1 & `Setosa_Sepal Length` > 3
    )) %>%
 tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "lightgreen")
      ),
    locations = cells_body(
                 columns =  vars(`Setosa_Sepal Width`),
                 rows = row == 1 & `Setosa_Sepal Width` > 3
    )) %>%
 tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "lightgreen")
      ),
    locations = cells_body(
                 columns =  vars(`Setosa_Petal Length`),
                 rows = row == 1 & `Setosa_Petal Length` > 3
    )) %>%
 tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "lightgreen")
      ),
    locations = cells_body(
                 columns =  vars(`Setosa_Petal Width`),
                 rows = row == 1 & `Setosa_Petal Width` > 3
    )) %>%
 tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = "lightgreen")
      ),
    locations = cells_body(
                 columns =  vars(`Versicolor_Sepal Length`),
                 rows = row == 1 & `Versicolor_Sepal Length` > 3
    )) %>% 
  tab_spanner_delim(
    delim="_"
  )
```

[image]